# Filter Options Using Checkboxes in an Excel VBA Userform

Tags: excel, checkbox, filter, userform, vba

I'm working on a `userform` that allows the end user to filter first by individual business units, then select the "flags" (0, 1, 2) they want to see. The `combobox` that lists the various business units works fine, it's the "flags" I'm having an issue with.

The users need to be able to select more than one flag to analyze. I orignally thought that using `Checkboxes` would be the way to go, however I can't seem to get the code to perform as I expect it to. If one `checkbox` is selected, it works fine, but if more than one is selected, it only filters by the value of the first `checkbox` selected.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Masterlist").Activate
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("I1").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=ComboBox1

With ActiveSheet
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
      ActiveSheet.Range("BL1").AutoFilter Field:=64, Criteria1:="0"
    ElseIf CheckBox2.Value = True Then
     ActiveSheet.Range("BL1").AutoFilter Field:=64, Criteria1:="1"
    ElseIf CheckBox3.Value = True Then
     ActiveSheet.Range("BL1").AutoFilter Field:=64, Criteria1:="2"
    End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Is there a better choice? Or can the code I already have be modified to work?

Comment: You probably need to build an `Array` of values based on the checkboxes.  You can then feed this `Array` to `Criteria1` to allow for multiple selection.